# Got hit by an OverflowException

Tags: c#, .net

In the Method below on the last line I'm always getting an exception:

```
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

I can't really explain why because I'm checking explicitly for that:

```
private Int32 ConvertValue(double value)
{
   if (value > Int32.MaxValue)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Couldn't convert value " + value + " to Int32");
      return Int32.MaxValue;
   }
   else if (value < Int32.MinValue)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Couldn't convert value " + value + " to Int32");
      return Int32.MinValue;
   }
   else
   {
      return Convert.ToInt32(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `value` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: try to write it all in `unchecked { }` block

Comment: What about if value == double.NaN? I doubt this would pass either of your tests.

Comment: Yes you gave me the correct hint. The problem seems to bee that it is 'n.def.' But the exception text gave me a wrong hint :(

Comment: I suspect that the problematic code is the one calling this method.

Comment: Meh, nothing quite like the kind of hurt you'll get from the CFO a year from now when she discovers why this year's balance sheet is showing such a massive loss.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also check `double.IsNaN(value)`.

Compares with `NaN` always yield false.

Comment: +1. Good call!. I wrote some code to test your answer and got the error. double d = Double.NaN; int i = Convert.ToInt32(d);

Answer (score 3):

Here's the source from Microsoft's `Convert.cs`:

```
public static int ToInt32(double value) {
    if (value >= 0) {
        if (value < 2147483647.5) {
            int result = (int)value; 
            double dif = value - result;
            if (dif > 0.5 || dif == 0.5 && (result & 1) != 0) result++; 
            return result; 
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (value >= -2147483648.5) {
            int result = (int)value;
            double dif = value - result; 
            if (dif < -0.5 || dif == -0.5 && (result & 1) != 0) result--;
            return result; 
        } 
    }
    throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32")); 
}
```

I don't know what value you are feeding it, but the answer should be obvious now.

Comment: Since he's testing the the input with Int32.MaxValue and Int32.MinValue, it doesn't seems obvious to me at all

Comment: @Krtek: If we knew what value was going in, it would be. But only the OP knows. If e.g. it's NaN, that would explain things.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception every time you run this function with any double value?

It worked fine for me.

Edit: I created a program with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 myInt = ConvertValue(86389327923.678);
            Console.WriteLine(myInt);
                    myInt = ConvertValue(-86389327923.678);
            Console.WriteLine(myInt);
                    myInt = ConvertValue(8.678);
            Console.WriteLine(myInt);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static private Int32 ConvertValue(double value)
        {
            if (value > Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't convert value " + value + " to Int32");
                return Int32.MaxValue;
            }
            else if (value < Int32.MinValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't convert value " + value + " to Int32");
                return Int32.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added exactly what I did in code. If there's a problem it's not with this code - that's a valid answer to this question imo.

Comment: Try running your ConvertValue against double.NaN. The error will occur

Comment: So as Henrik suggests you need an extra check for double.NaN. I don't understand how you could get the OverflowException if you add this check in? The question doesn't help too much in that it doesn't actually stipulate which values the original code doesn't work for. I see nothing unusal here at all.

Comment: If I would have known this before asking this question I could have answered it myself. But unfortunately the exception message ''value is to small or to great'' gave my a hint in the wrong direction.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. :) Thanks guys, this has given me some help with answering and troubleshooting issues.